# Mongoose - pre-populate One-To-Many relationships in model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am building a table planner for my wedding which involves assigning guests to tables. I have a 'table' model with the following Schema:

```js
const tableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please provide the name of the table',
    trim: true
  },
  capacity: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Please provide the capacity of the table',
  },
  guests: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Guest',
  }
});
```

I expect each record of the Table model to have a property called guests which will return an array of guest ids. I have set up the following JSON file to import:

```js
[
  {
    "firstname": "Name1",
    "surname": "Surname1",
    "table": "5ad9fe819c2a33f9edcd33b5"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Name2",
    "surname": "Surname2",
    "table": "5ad9fe819c2a33f9edcd33b5"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Name3",
    "surname": "Surname3",
    "table": "5ad9fe819c2a33f9edcd33b5"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Name4",
    "surname": "Surname4",
    "table": "5ad9fe819c2a33f9edcd33b5"
  }
]
```

But when I try to import it I get the following error:

> Cast to ObjectID failed for value  "[ '5ae2e655c122b654ba3765b4',
>   '5ae2e655c122b654ba3765b5',   '5ae2e655c122b654ba3765b6',
>   '5ae2e655c122b654ba3765b7',   '5ae2e655c122b654ba3765b8' ]" at path
>   "guests"

The array looks fine to me and the import script I'm using worked fine when I used it for importing data to another model which didn't contain arrays.

Any ideas?

Comment: You appear to be under the misconception that mongoose is going to create your related guests entries in another collection for you. It will NOT. That is up to you to do yourself, as well as include the child references either 1. In the parent as an "array" of `ObjectId` values 2. With a property on the child denoting the parent and establishing a "virtual" property defining the relation. In short, none of this is as "magical" as you appear to be presuming. Read the documentation again, and probably try working with some of the sample code before writing your own

Comment: If you want to build relationships why not go with MySQL or any other relational database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have wrongly defined `guests` as `ObjectId`, instead it should be array of `ObjectIds`. And, that is why it is not able to convert array of `ObjectIds` to an `ObjectId`, Hence the above error.

You schema should look something like this :

```
const tableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please provide the name of the table',
    trim: true
  },
  capacity: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Please provide the capacity of the table',
  },
  guests: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Guest',
  }]
})
```

Comment: This did the trick. Classic coding problem that two square brackets cause hours of pain!